# Find duplicates in a list of lists with tuples

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x, set

I am trying to find duplicates within tuples that are nested within a list. This whole construction is a list too. If there are other better ways to organize this to let my problem to be solved - I'd be glad to know, because this is something I build on the way.

```
pairsList = [
                [1, (11, 12), (13, 14)], #list1
                [2, (21, 22), (23, 24)], #list2
                [3, (31, 32), (13, 14)], #list3
                [4, (43, 44), (21, 22)], #list4
               ]
```

The first element in each list uniquely identifies each list.

From this object `pairsList`, I want to find out which lists have identical tuples. So I want to report that `list1` has the same tuple as `list3` (because both have `(13,14)`. Likewise, `list2` and `list4` have the same tuple (both have `(21,22)`) and need to be reported. The position of tuples within the list doesn't matter (`list2` and `list4` both have `(13,14)` even though the position in the list the tuple has is different).

The output result could be anything iterable later on such as `(1,3),(2,4)` or `[1,3],[2,4]`. It is the pairs I am interested in.

I am aware of sets and have used them to delete duplicates within the lists in other situations, but cannot understand how to solve this problem. I can check like this if one list contains any element from the other list:

```
list1 = [1, (11, 12), (13, 14)]
list2 = [3, (31, 32), (13, 14)]
print not set(list1).isdisjoint(list2)
>>>True
```

So, the code below lets me know what lists have same tuple(s) as the first one. But what is the correct way to perform this on all the lists?

```
counter = 0
for pair in pairsList:
    list0 = pairsList[0]
    iterList = pairsList[counter]
    if not set(list0).isdisjoint(iterList):
        print iterList[0] #print list ID
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The first element in each list uniquely identifies each list.*

Great, then let's convert it to a dict first:

```
d = {x[0]: x[1:] for x in pairsList}

# d: 
{1: [(11, 12), (13, 14)],
 2: [(21, 22), (23, 24)],
 3: [(31, 32), (13, 14)],
 4: [(43, 44), (21, 22)]}
```

Let's index the whole data structure:

```
index = {}
for k, vv in d.iteritems():
    for v in vv:
        index.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

Now `index` is:

```
{(11, 12): [1],
 (13, 14): [1, 3],
 (21, 22): [2, 4],
 (23, 24): [2],
 (31, 32): [3],
 (43, 44): [4]}
```

*The output result could be anything iterable later on such as (1,3),(2,4) or [1,3],[2,4]. It is the pairs I am interested in.*

```
pairs = [v for v in index.itervalues() if len(v) == 2]
```

returns `[[1,3],[2,4]]`.

Comment: I was thinking of using `defaultdict(set)` and then `itertools.combinations` on the set to get all such pairs. For example if we add `[5, (11, 12), (21, 22)]
` in `pairList` then combinations can help us return `[(1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (4, 5) ]`

Comment: I meant `combinations(v, 2)`, `v` from the last list-comprehension.

Comment: @eumiro, this would take me a long time to solve, a bit too advanced with dictionary iterators. The solution works fine. I have modified the ``if len(v) == 2]`` to be ``if len(v) > 1]`` so I could get as output lists where there were multiple cases of having the same tuple. Sorry for confusion with "pairs" word - I just didn't want to overcomplicate my question. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov - I was hesitating (even editing) between `== 2` and `> 1` and finally considered the name `pairs`. Glad to have shown you the dict comprehension, you'll love to use it.